# reset existing content type settings to default settings

Tags: nodes

In my Drupal 7 Site, I have a couple of Nodes of the same content type. On some of them, the settings( Menu, Sitemap) have been changed.
How can I reset all of them to the default settings for that content type?
thanks in advance

Comment: use node_load_multiple() to load all nodes and change the value for menu/path and save them using node_save()

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: That won’t automatically set them back to the default

Comment: You can reset the setting for the future nodes but for the nodes which are already created you cannot do that. For the nodes which are already created you have to fire a query to get the node id and then create a array of it and pass it to node_load_multiple() function which is going to give you the list of node objects. You can loop through it and alter the data in it and then save it one by one using node_save().

Comment: can you maybe give me an idiot proof tutorial?